# How can I use dynamic typed template during executing?

Tags: c++, templates

say I have a class template `A`, I want to dynamically instantiate it to `foo<int>` or `foo<float>`. i.e.

(pseudocode, please don't pay attention to the scope issue)

```
if (exp) {
    foo<int> f();
}
else {
    foo<float> f();
}

// use foo ...
```

I know in classic C++ the template is instantiate during compiling, but is there any new tricks in modern C++ enable the pattern before? I don't want write duplicate codes for every type.

What about this?

```
std::variant<foo<int>, foo<float>> f;
if (use_int) {
    f = foo<int>();   } 
else {
    f = foo<float>();   }
```

Comment: Aside: Most vexing parse.

Comment: There's a whiff of XY problem about this. _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: 1) "template is instantiate during compiling" 2) You can't use a variable after it goes out of scope. 3) the rest of the code needs know the type of f (If you get f to exist for it.) That said, are you familiar with std::any and std::variant?

Comment: I hope that users can enter whether to use float type when executing

Comment: ... and then what? What is `foo` used for? What does it do? Does it inherit some common base class that contains all of your write-it-once logic?

Comment: no, there's not any inheritance.

Comment: Minor suggestion based on your edit:  `f = use_int ? foo<int>() : foo<float>();`

Comment: Is there any article specifically discussing the advantages and disadvantages of my logic?

Comment: `f = use_int ? foo<int>() : foo<float>();`? this cannot compile even.

Comment: Why not write a templated function add pass `f` to that when you instantiate it?

Comment: Great idea! I'll try then. But is my original idea really awkward and couldn't find any way to do?

Comment: `foo<int>` and `foo<float>` are two different, totally unrelated classes.  Having a variable that can hold either one (and then using it later), is indeed awkward and non-trivial.  Your question is essentially "how can I have a variable that's either a string or a number, decided at runtime?", and the answer will be essentially the same.

Comment: Use `constexpr if`

Comment: You can also make the entire code that uses `foo` templated?

Comment: Probably jus a typo in your first paragraph, but how are you instantiating your `A` template with `foo<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid duplicating code for multiple types is to use a template, and the "standard solution" to most problems is to add a level of indirection - for instance, through a function.
Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
   // Whatever ...
};

template<typename T>
void use_foo_with()
{
    Foo<T> foot;
    // Use foot ...
}

void something(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
        use_foo_with<int>();
    else
        use_foo_with<float>();
}
```